# How to split an string into pairs of numbers?

Tags: node.js

I am using a `regex` to extract telephone numbers, I achieve to extract the number from a text, however, I need the final output:

```
50 40 60 55 85
```

I tried as follows:

```
function extract_number(string){
  const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
  let value;
  try {
    const result = string.match(regex)
    value = result[0]
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('There was an error, the string don', err);
  }

    for (var i=0; i < value.length; i++) { 
     //console.log(value.charAt(i));
     var temporal =  value.charAt(i)
     var final = temporal + ' '
     console.log(final)
    }

}
```

However, when I run my function as follows:

```
extract_number('my number is 5540605585')
```

I only got:

```
node index.js 
5 
5 
4 
0 
6 
0 
5 
5 
8 
5 
<Buffer 68 6f 6c 61 20 6d 75 6e 64 6f>
```

So I would like to appreciate support to achieve the task, additionally I do not know why I am getting:

```
 <Buffer 68 6f 6c 61 20 6d 75 6e 64 6f>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function extract_number(string) {
  const regex = /(?:(\+?\d{1,3}) )?(?:([\(]?\d+[\)]?)[ -])?(\d{1,5}[\- ]?\d{1,5})/
  let value;
  try {
    const result = string.match(regex)
    value = result[0]
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('There was an error, the string don', err);
  }
  const formatted_number = value.toString().replace(/\d{2}(?=.)/g, '$& ')
  console.log(formatted_number)
}

extract_number('my number is 5540605585')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, I really appreciate the support